# How do I upgrade my kernel in CentOS 6 to the latest version?

Tags: linux, centos, grub, kernel, digital-ocean

It's giving me problems and is not using the latest, even after power cycling.

```
[root@server ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64
[root@server ~]# cat /boot/grub.conf
cat: /boot/grub.conf: No such file or directory
[root@server ~]# cat /boot/grub/grub.conf
cat: /boot/grub/grub.conf: No such file or directory
[root@server ~]# yum reinstall kernel
Running Transaction
  Installing : kernel-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                         1/1
  Verifying  : kernel-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                         1/1

Installed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.20.1.el6

Complete!
[root@server ~]# less /etc/grub.conf
/etc/grub.conf: No such file or directory
[root@server ~]# poweroff
Broadcast message from root@server
        (/dev/pts/0) at 23:11 ...

The system is going down for power off NOW!
Chloe@xps ~/workspace/
$ ssh root@server
Last login: Thu Feb 15 23:07:40 2018 from 
[root@server ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64
[root@server ~]# rpm -q kernel
kernel-2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64
[root@server ~]#
```

CentOS 6

Comment: An enterprise grade server OS like CentOS 6 will keep the stable kernel version in it´s full lifetime. The CentOS 6 kernel-2.3.32 is constantly updated with security patches. And new features from later kernel versions are also added. New "drivers" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listed all the kernels and deleted all the old others.

```
[root@server ~]# rpm -q kernel
kernel-2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64
[root@server ~]# rpm --erase kernel-2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64 kernel-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 kernel-2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64
```